# GridViewDataTextColumn - input string was not in a correct format with masked value

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have the GridViewDataTextColumn with Masked valued i.e 0.00 % since there is a % symbol inside the TextBox am getting error while inserting and updating the data. The error is input string was not in a correct format. How to fix this error?

Here is my aspx code,

```
     <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FillPercent" Caption="Fill Percent" VisibleIndex="9" Width="7%" 
                                Settings-AutoFilterCondition="Contains">                            
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True" Wrap="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True"></CellStyle>
                                <PropertiesTextEdit Width="250px" MaxLength="10" DisplayFormatString="{0}%">   
                                    <MaskSettings Mask="<0..100>.<00..99> %" />                                                                      
                                </PropertiesTextEdit>  
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Here is my Sample screenshot

[image: Click here to see the image]

Comment: why are you specifying % in edit mask.. If you do so then it will defiantly save value with % symbol.. just use % symbol in display format only after it may solve your issue.

Comment: I want the % symbol inside the textbox always that is why i masked % symbol in editform

Comment: Why setting  DisplayFormatString="P" is not a satisfying solution for you?